# Java: call notFull.signal() in ArrayBlockingQueue put method is a bug?

Tags: java

In `ArrayBlockingQueue`, inside the `put method`, I don't understand why does it call `notFull.signal()` after catching `InterruptedException`. If the `thread1` and `thread2` are waiting for `notFull` together,and thread 3 interrupts thread 1. Thread 1 catch the `interruptedException` and signal the thread2,thread2 put the element into the items,but items is still full,is this a bug?

put method code:

```
public void put(E e) throws InterruptedException {
    if (e == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    final E[] items = this.items;
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        try {
            while (count == items.length)
                notFull.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            notFull.signal(); // propagate to non-interrupted thread
            throw ie;
        }
        insert(e);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you missing the while loop there that continuously checks for the size? It'll just call `await()` again. An element won't be added until it breaks out of the while loop.

Comment: +1 you're right,I didn't noitce the while loop,thanks